# Given QVariant, get reference to variable with some type

Tags: c++, qt

I have QVector of QVariants. To implement the interface of my class i should implement getter, that will return constant reference to data, stored in this vector. It looks like:

```
const QString& getSomeProperty()
{
    return value<QString>(0);
}

template <typename MyType>
const T& value (int index)
{
    const MyType* ptr = static_cast<const MyType*>(m_d.at(index).constData());
    if (ptr)
        return *ptr;
    else
        return static_cast<T>(QVariant());
}

QVector<QVariant> m_d;
```

I can't use vector of non QVariants, because there is need to store different types.  I can't use Qt3 methods (asString, asBool ...). Is there a better way to do what I am doing?

Comment: Are only pointers stored in the `QVariant`s?

Comment: I don't store pointers in QVariants.

Comment: Then why are you trying to cast to a pointer?  And `QVariant::constData()` doesn't exist.

Comment: <br>`QVariant v = QString("hello world");`<br/>
<br>`const QString * str = static_cast<const QString*><br>(v.constData());`<br/>
<br>`if (str)`<br/>
    <br>`std::cout << str->toStdString().c_str();`<br/> This prints `Hello world`

Comment: Wow, I don't how you found that, it's not in here: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant-members.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, if I understood you correctly. However, the following code will extract the variant at position `index` from your vector and return its value as a const-reference to `T`. If the variant does not store a `T`, you still have to return a `T`. Thus, you need some default value, which you can return in this case.

```
template <typename T>
const T& value(int index)
{
    // Some value to return, if the variant does not store a T.
    static T defaultValue;

    const QVariant& variant = m_d.at(index);

    // If the variant stores a T, return it.
    if (variant.userType() == qMetaTypeId<T>())
        return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(variant.constData());

    // Return the default value. Or add an assertion here. Or throw
    // an exception etc.
    return defaultValue;
}
```

This simple test case

```
m_d.push_back(10);
m_d.push_back(QString("Hello"));
m_d.push_back(3.14);

// This returns what is stored in the vector.
qDebug() << value<int>(0);
qDebug() << value<QString>(1);
qDebug() << value<double>(2);

// This returns the default value.
qDebug() << value<int>(1);
qDebug() << value<QString>(2);
qDebug() << value<double>(0);
```

produces the following output

```
10
"Hello"
3.14
0
""
0
```

where you can see that the last three queries return the default value.

**Note:** The Qt containers often pass a default `T` to the functions (e.g. `QMap::value()`) which they return, if they could not find the requested element. You might also try to use something like

```
template <typename T>
T value(int index, const T& defaultValue = T())
{
    ...
}
```

**Edit:** Fixed returning a const-reference from temporary.

Comment: The problem is that your code returns reference to variable, that was created on stack of `value` function. `warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary`